# Ending of "Strangers On A Train"

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, strangers-on-a-train

In Hitchcock's *Strangers On A Train* when Bruno visits Guy after murdering his wife the latter wants to go the police. Bruno stops him, saying that he will be arrested for involvement, i.e. they won't believe that it was Bruno's initiative. Guy later says the same to his fiancee, when she finds out.

At the very end Guy is released and no charges are pressed against him, while his situation is exactly the same, the only difference being the fact that Bruno wanted to set him up using the lighter. However if Guy was involved in the murders and Bruno wanted to frame him as being the actual killer (for whatever reason) it would look exactly the same for the police.

Based on the above why the police believed Guy, if it seems that his cooperation with Bruno and later disagreement was much more plausible than Bruno killing on his own and then trying to set up Guy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just after the murder, a man working at the carnival recognizes Bruno as a suspect. (While everyone is watching the commotion, Bruno calmly walks away without paying any attention to the commotion and so catches the attention of this man.)

(Someone at IMDB labeled this man "Boatman", but I didn't see any indication that he worked on the boats.)

[image]

[image]

Near the end of the movie when they are all back at the carnival and Guy and Bruno are on the merry-go-round, he tells the police (who initially misinterpret this as referring to Guy):

[image]

The end of the movie doesn't explain how exactly the case was subsequently handled, but I think the above testimony by "Boatman" would've been sufficient to acquit Guy had the case gone to trial.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I didn't expect to get it after 7 years. That indeed could have been enough for the police to not believe Guy's story.

Answer (score -3):

Truth is, Guy probably told the police *Half* the truth. Could be as simple as saying "yeah I was on a train and I left my lighter in a dining car. The guy then tracked me down and told me hes was gonna frame me. Etc, Etc.

I don't believe that the film actually ends with him not having any charges pressed, just that he goes free in the end. SOOOO in short in doesn't matter HOW. Just that the police wouldn't have had enough evidence to convict by a LONG shot, so they might not have even bothered.